# How do I create a binary (0 or 1 valued) tensor according to known index in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

input: length(placeholder), index(1D tensor)
output: 0-1 1D tensor
example: length 5, index [0,1,3], output tensor should be [1,1,0,1,0]

I have tried `scatter_add`, which requires `Variable` which requires known shape, and `embedding_lookup` from matrix with [length, length], which is not effective when length is large.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try [tf.sparse_to_dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense):

```
output_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [1])
index = tf.constant([0, 1, 3])
ones = tf.ones([tf.size(index)])
result = tf.sparse_to_dense(index, output_size, ones)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(result, feed_dict={output_size: [5]})
```

Outputs: `array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.], dtype=float32)`